# How to get the right cells closer to left celss in TableLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following code:

```
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/table"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:shrinkColumns="*"
        android:stretchColumns="*"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/table_row1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_project1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="text"/>

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner_project2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" />
        </TableRow>


        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/table_row2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_project2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Very long test"/>

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner_project2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout
```

It basically creates the following table:

```
text                         [spinner]
very long text               [spinner]
```

I want the spinner to be closer to the text so I don't want the row to be 50-50. Rather I want to take the longest string in the text and this will be the size of the cells in the first column. I will get:

```
text            [spinner]  <Nothing here>
very long text  [spinner]  <Nothing here>
```

I tried to use `marginLeft` but it didn't help. I also tried use `weights=3` with inserting empty text-view. It looks better but then I get empty textview in the middle of the code. I'm sure there is a way to do it. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use  `android:shrinkColumns="1"` for `TableLayout` currently you are using * and remove `android:stretchColumns="*"`

```
<TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/table"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:shrinkColumns="1"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/table_row1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_project1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="text"/>

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" />

        </TableRow>


        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/table_row2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_project2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Very long test"/>

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner_2"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" />

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

> Note : Indexing starts from 0 i.e if you want to shrink/stretch 1st
>   column you have to use 0 not 1